# in cocos2d-iphone, how to make CCScrollLayer scroll pixel by pixedl, but not page by page

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

in cocos2d-iphone, how to make CCScrollLayer scroll pixel by pixel, but not page by page.
I have used UIScrollView to intead CCScrollLayer in cocos2d, but the effect is not good, when transit between scene, the UIScrollView shows while transiting.
is anyone knows? Thanks in advance!!!
if you still dont know my question, please ask me.